# Not able to display the name of the file selected

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've modified the input [type = file] and could get it to a button with a green background. The code used is as follows:

```
<style>
    #file {
        height:0px;
        opacity:0;
    }  
    #span {
        left:0px;
        position:absolute;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>

<form name="form">
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file"/>
    <span id="span" style="background-color: #7FFFD4">Select a file</span>

</form>

<script>
    var span = document.getElementById("span");

    span.onclick = function(event) {
        document.form.file.click(event);
    };

</script>
```

Now I am not able to view the selected file. Is there any way i can view the file that i selected next to the button??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why same thing declared 2 times? Is it actual code or you just paste it 2 times here? And tag your questions properly so that you may find appropriate solution!

Comment: sorry, i just pasted it twice.

Comment: You can also styling your input type="file" by following [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html) tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You cant see the filename because you have set the height of the input element and its opacity to zero. You can set opacity to 1, and reposition the span to cover the "choose file" button such as something like this (works for me on chrome):

```
 #file {
      opacity: 1;
 }
 #span {
      left: 3px;
      position: absolute;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 10px;
      top: 3px;
 }
```

You also might want to check out [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to keep input type file as hidden and want to show its file name to span. you can do something like below.

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="file" onchange="ChangeText(this, 'span');"/>
    <span id="span" style="background-color: #7FFFD4">Select a file</span>

function ChangeText(oFileInput, sTargetID) {

    document.getElementById(sTargetID).value = oFileInput.value;
}
```